# How to write an extension method for DataTable.Rows[i][j]?

Tags: c#, datatable, extension-methods, tostring, datarow

I would like to create an extension method to be implemented like below (if it is even possible) which would be similar to the `.ToString()` extension method.  Can someone please point me in the right direction.  I attempted to search it in Google and cannot locate anything.

```
DataTable table = db.GetInfo(UserId);
if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     bool b = table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].MyExtensionMethod();
}
```

I would essentially like to simplify this:

```
bool b = Convert.IsDBNull(table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"]) ? false : bool.Parse(table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].ToString());
```

to

```
bool b = table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].DbBoolNullable();
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Comment: That's `object`.  `ToString()` is not an extension method.

Comment: I made a revision to my question... I am relatively new to programming so please excuse me if I am misstating my question.

Comment: To add to SLaks comment, the term "extension" method is a specific kind of method that you probably don't need to be concerned with if you are new to programming. You should by writing just a "method". "ToString()" is not an extension method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [indexer of DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/146h6tk5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a System.Object, your best bet is something like the following:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool DbBoolNullable(this object o)
    {
        return Convert.IsDBNull(o) ? false : bool.Parse(o.ToString());
    }
}
```

However, **I'd strongly advise against this**, as since this is an extension method for `System.Object` (which every class in .NET inherits from), then this method will apply to *every variable*.

A better way would probably to make an extension method for `DataRow`:

```
public static bool GetBool(this DataRow row, string column)
{
   return Convert.IsDbNull(row[column]) ? false : bool.Parse(row[column].ToString());
}
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
bool val = table.Rows[0].GetBool("ColumnName");
```

Comment: The second option (recommended) works like a charm!!! Thank you for that clarification and insight on why it is better to implement at the `DataRow` level.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like,

```
public static bool DbBoolNullable(this object cell)
{
    return Convert.IsDBNull(cell) ? false : bool.Parse(cell.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This:  `table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"]` returns an *Object*.

If you write an extension method for an object, every single class in .Net will get the extension.   Try something else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off writing the extension method at the `DataRow` level, or even the `DataTable`, instead of `object`. First, you'd avoid polluting `object`, and it would let you skip some ugly syntax.

So instead of:

```
table.Rows[0]["ColumnName"].DbBoolNullable()
```

You could do the extension at the table and end up with:

```
table.DbBoolNullable(0, "ColumnName")

public static bool DbBoolNullable(this DataTable table, int rowNum, string colName)
{
    return Convert.IsDBNull(table.Rows[rowNum][colName])
        ? false 
        : bool.Parse(table.Rows[rowNum][colName].ToString());
}
```

Or do it at the row and end up with:

```
table.Rows[0].DbBoolNullable("ColumnName")

public static bool DbBoolNullable(this DataRow row, string colName)
{
    return Convert.IsDBNull(row[colName])
        ? false 
        : bool.Parse(row[colName].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5599559/467473 — a while back, I wrote a bunch of extension methods to do just the sort of thing you're wanting to do. To extend this technique, you'll be wanting to look at [the documentation on type mapping between C# and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx).

Further, if your using a recentish version of the .Net CLR, take a look at [System.Data.DataRowExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.aspx), which might be just the thing that you're looking for.