# DataTable Extension methods C#

Tags: c#

I have a method to perform operation in Datatable.

```
public DataTable SetColumnsOrder(DataTable table, String[] columnNames)
    {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            if (table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
            {
                table.Columns[columnName].SetOrdinal(columnIndex);
                columnIndex++;
            }
        } return table;
    }
```

To access this method I need to do like this

```
dt = SetColumnsOrder(dt,colNames);
```

Instead of doing like this, how to create a function to call it like below in c#

```
dt.SetColumnOrder(colNames);
```

where the function should take dt as input to perform operations and store back in same dt.

Comment: You are assigning the `DataTable` object in the above code, it looks like you want to assign a function to the `DataTable` object and call it's `SetColumnOrder` function?

Comment: while this is not exactly a duplicate of questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20406902/how-to-write-an-extension-method-for-datatable-rowsij), there is little merit adding 3+ answers to this question; it is asking about a common [feature of the language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

Answer (score 3):

You would need to use an extension method like so:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static DataTable SetColumnsOrder(this DataTable table, string[] columnNames)
    {
        int columnIndex = 0;
        foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
        {
            if (table.Columns.Contains(columnName))
            {
                table.Columns[columnName].SetOrdinal(columnIndex);
                columnIndex++;
            }
        }
        return table;
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
dt.SetColumnsOrder(columnNames);
```

And since you're modifying the DataTable, which is a reference type.  You can use void as the return type and just access the sorted `dt` variable

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to return the same DataTable that you pass in. You could change your method signature to:

```
public void SetColumnsOrder(DataTable table, String[] columnNames)
```

and remove the `return`, and it would still work the same (obviously you'd call it like `SetColumnsOrder(dt,colNames);` instead of `dt = SetColumnsOrder(dt,colNames);`. And you *should* do that, because it's less confusing design.

Then, in order to call it as an extension method, just change the signature again, to:

```
public static void SetColumnsOrder(this DataTable table, String[] columnNames)
```

And now you can use it like `dt.SetColumnOrder(colNames);`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your signature from

```
public DataTable SetColumnsOrder(DataTable table, String[] columnNames)
```

to

```
public static DataTable SetColumnsOrder(this DataTable table, String[] columnNames)
```

Comment: Don't forget to make the method `static`.