# nullable decimal from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, nullable, sqldatareader

I use SqlDataReader to read some values from SQL data table. Value is decimal, but it call also be null. How do I assign it? I have tried it like this, but it throws "Specified cast is not valid" exception, if myValue is null.

```
decimal? d= (decimal)myRdr["myValue"];
```

What is the best way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding null value in Dataset - DataRow.IsNull method vs ==DbNull.Value - c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599390/finding-null-value-in-dataset-datarow-isnull-method-vs-dbnull-value-c-shar)

Comment: Not a duplicate of [Finding null value in Dataset - DataRow.IsNull method vs ==DbNull.Value - c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599390/finding-null-value-in-dataset-datarow-isnull-method-vs-dbnull-value-c-shar), that is about testing if a value is null, this is about casting a nullable value from the reader to a variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this ?

```
decimal? d= myRdr["myValue"] == DBNull.Value ? null : (decimal?)myRdr["myValue"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
decimal? d = myRdr["myValue"] != DBNull.Value ? (decimal)myRdr["myValue"] : null;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
decimal? d = myRdr["myValue"] == DBNull.Value ? null : decimal.Parse(myRdr["myValue"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal? d = myRdr[columnName] as decimal?;
```

And the above, in an extension method:

```
public static decimal? GetNullableDecimal(this SqlDataReader myRdr, string columnName, decimal? valueIfNull = null)
{
    return myRdr[columnName] as decimal? ?? valueIfNull;
}
```

Usage:

```
decimal? d = myRdr.GetNullableDecimal("myValue");
decimal? d = myRdr.GetNullableDecimal("myValue", valueIfNull: 0);
```

*footnote*

Disclaimer. I've only read this, not tested it: "as" casting is said to be 5x faster than prefix (explicit) casting: http://gen5.info/q/2008/06/13/prefix-casting-versus-as-casting-in-c/